# Installing KitKat on rooted Jelly bean Nexus 7

Tags: updates, nexus-7, unrooting, 4.4-kitkat, twrp

I have a nexus 7 2012, and I have it rooted, running TWRP recovery and Franco kernel. I want to update to KitKat, and I have the OTA queued (but that won't work since I'm rooted) and I have the file for my device downloaded from [this site with update info](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/21/here-are-the-manual-update-links-for-the-last-nexus-devices-to-get-kitkat-otas-2013-nexus-7-lte-and-2012-nexus-7-3g-android-4-4-krt16s/), but I tried installing it in TWRP and it gave me an error. How can I get this update?

If I need to unroot and uninstall TWRP and Franco Kernel, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to flash back to the stock kernel as files linked on that site will only apply to a 'stock' system partition. You should be able to flash the file via TWRP by selecting it (I presume you've tried this as you said that it gave you an error).

To flash back to the stock kernel you will need to find the stock kernel image (ideally you would have a backup from before you flashed the Franco kernel) and then you can install the update.

edit: You may be able to find the stock kernel on [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=38201936&postcount=2) xda post

Comment: Ah, I had no idea you could flash those in Recovery. I guess I always had a custom kernel, so always needed to use fastboot. Updated my answer so it doesn't say fastboot is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, you can flash those images in Fastboot. Remember to make a Nandroid and back it up somewhere safe - this will wipe your device.

If you're on Windows or OSX, you'll need to install Fastboot through the Android SDK. It's part of the "Platform Tools" package. If you're on Linux, you can usually install fastboot through your package manager.

Additionally, Windows needs [ADB and fastboot drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.htm) for your device.

First, you need to boot your device into fastboot/bootloader mode by holding down the Volume Down button while powering on. You can also use an expanded reboot menu or ADB: `adb reboot bootloader`.

Second, unzip the file you've downloaded. Remember where you unzipped it to.

On Windows:

- Optional: Add the path to your Android Platform-tools (ADB and Fastboot) to your PATH environment variable.
- Open an elevated Command Prompt. (I think elevating it was necessary)
- In the Command Prompt, navigate to the unzipped Android files.
- Type `flash-all.bat` and press Enter.

  - If this doesn't work, you will need to specify the location of the fastboot.exe file by modifying the `PATH=%PATH%...` line in the `flash-all.bat` file.

On Linux or OSX:

- Unzip the downloaded .zip file.
- Open a terminal.
- Navigate to the unzipped files in the terminal.
- Type `./flash-all.sh` and press Enter.

Comment: How about if I'm on Mac?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat Ah, then just follow the Linux steps. I'll also update the answer. You'll need to install Fastboot from the Android SDK (If you have ADB, you have Fastboot usually), but you won't need drivers.